# Why Laplace transform equals zero if and only if $f(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, statistics

The question is how to show the Laplace transform of $L(f(x))=\int_0^{ + \infty } {f(x){e^{ - sx}}dx}  = 0$ if and only if $f(x)=0$?

The question arises when I watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1cmSOaEak8&index=14&list=PLbMVogVj5nJRkNUH5v9qNEJvW7r2A7rEY at 57:00, when the professor tries to prove normal distribution $N(\mu,1)$ is complete by stating $\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {g(x){e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{2}}}{e^{\mu x}}dx}  = 0$ if and only if $g(x)=0$. The following is a scree capture.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Prove the statement for step functions, then simple functions and finally take a uniform limit of simple functions to show the result for all functions $f(x)$.

Comment: ^What Alex said for the "only if"; the "if" is quite simple (the integral of zero is zero).